# Adding Cleaver (PhoneGap / Cordova as component) view to an existing ViewController's view hierarchy

Tags: ios, cordova

The [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS) for using PhoneGap / Cordova WebView as an embedded component recommends doing:

```
[myView addSubview:viewController.view];
```

to embed the view.

Isn't it bad practice for a view to belong to multiple controllers? I thought it would cause issues with messages like `-viewWillAppear:` or `-didReceiveMemoryWarning`..

Can anyone confirm for me that reaching into the instantiated `CDVViewController`, grabbing its view and then adding it to my own controllers view hierarchy is the right approach?